# Is it possible to dynamically change http request host value using maven profile on mule?

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm a newbie on MuleSoft. I created a Maven Mule Project and one of my flows have the component Http Request. This component has the attribute "host". However, I have 2 environments: Test and Production. Is it possible to dynamically change the "host" attribute value, depending the profile created on maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sudarshan helped me a lot! However, the maven solution was not working. What I did was:

On maven, I added the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-active-profile-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>
                            ${project.build.outputDirectory}/conf-app.properties
                        </outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

To create the profile on maven, what I did was:

```
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <host>999.999.999.999</host>
            <port>8080</port>
            <basePath>/v1</basePath>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then, in the xml flow located on src/main/app my HTTP Request is as the following:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="${host}" port="${port}" basePath="${basePath}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"
    connectionIdleTimeout="180000" />
```

To run the profile created, use the following command on maven:

```
mvn clean package -Paq -X
```

After that, you will be good to go!

Comment: that is strange because I have this configuration working on multiple live apps. The trouble with your answer is that all the env specific settings will end up in the pom. If you upload your project(subset) somewhere I wouldn't mind having a look at it.but great that you cracked it.

Answer (score 2):

Good question! What you are actually looking for is environment specific configurations.

Mule build on Maven profiles and provides this Out of the box (OOTB)

Have a look at this [link](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Deploying+to+Multiple+Environments)

To summarize configure the http endpoint as below

```
<http:listener-config name="HttpListenerConfiguration"
                    doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"
                    host="${mule.env.host}"
                    port="${mule.env.port}"
                    basePath="${mule.env.path}" />
```

and then have a environment specific property file

```
qa.basePath=test/products
qa.host=localhost
qa.port=8082

prod.basePath=products
prod.host=www.acme.com
prod.port=8081
```

At build time you would specify that you are building for a specific environment and those specific values would get replaced within your configurations

**Update: Choosing a property file based on Maven profile**

Create environment specific property files, so your project structure and pom.xml will look something like the below

[image: pom.xml and project structure]

I do remember having some trouble around the resources section, so pasting the relevant section here

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>                                    
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource> 
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>                                  
                                </resource>                             
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Your mule-project.xml should look like the below

[image: mule-project.xml]

With this sorted just choose a profile in your maven build

mvn clean compile package -P qa

Comment: Awesome! The link was really helpful! However, the properties control is made on the **Environment variables** where I can define if it is a "QA" environment or a "Production" environment on  the root mule-project.xml. However, my question still remains: Is it possible to change that control to a maven profile?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do let me know if this worked out for you.

Comment: I made exactly what you did on your update answer. However, when running the profile the following error appears: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'C:\Users\Gabriel\AnypointStudio\bus\bus\target\bus1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip' does not exist at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:767)**.
It seems that the zip is not being created when executing with the profile. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the problem. I was using mvn clean compile package clean install -P qa. Using the **mvn clean compile package -P qa** worked fine! However the other error is **java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${mule.env.value}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist**. It seems that the **Environment Variable ${mule.env.value}** is not being replaced by the value we defined on the pom profile

Comment: Actually no. As I said in the last comment, the **Environment Variable ${mule.env.value}** was not being replaced with the value defined on the pom profile. Below, I will answer how I solved my problem.